# VBA Loop error. Only pasting one result

Tags: arrays, string, vba, loops, copy-paste

If AG_Label = M_Label the code runs and pastes but only for the first instance.
There is something wrong with my loop but I am very new to VBA and so I do not know how to fix it.

```
    Dim mrow As Long, ARow As Long, iRows As Long, srow As String
Dim x As Long, j As Long, i As Long
Dim AG_Label As String, AG_val As String, SNL_val As String, SNL_Label As String, M_Label As String, Rng As Range
Dim Vval As Long, Speriod As String, aperiod As String
Dim Count As Integer, Ajay As Variant

Count = 2

ARow = Sheets("AG").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Do
For i = 2 To ARow
    AG_Label = Sheets("AG").Cells(i, "N").Value
    'mrow = Sheets("Mappings").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    'For j = 2 To mrow
        'M_Match_1 = Sheets("Mappings").Cells(j, "P").Value
        M_Label = Sheets("Mappings").Cells(Count, "C").Value


        If AG_Label = M_Label And Sheets("Mappings").Cells(Count, "L").Value = "FRY-9C" Then
            Sheets("Mappings").Cells(Count, "J").copy
            Sheets("AG").Cells(i, "AM").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
              Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                On Error Resume Next
        End If

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Next
'i = i + 1

Loop Until i = ARow + 1

Count = Count + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: For starters, fix this line - `ARow = Sheets("AG").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` with a qualified reference to Rows like this - `ARow = Sheets("AG").Range("A" & Sheets("AG").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Your `Count = Count + 1` immediately before the `End Sub` seems suspicious - there is absolutely no point incrementing a procedure-level variable and then discarding it by exiting the procedure.   Should that be inside your loop somewhere?

Comment: Comment out that `On Error Resume Next` unless there's a good reason for it there.

Comment: Your `Do` `...` `Loop Until i = ARow + 1` is pointless - the value of `i` when it hits the `Loop` statement will be `ARow + 1`, so the `Do` loop is being executed exactly once - never less, never more.

Comment: @YowE3K yes there is a problem there. It looks through the AG_Label but when that is complete till the last row, how do I then increment M_Label so that is goes through the same If statement again for the new M_label value

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks Tim. This was in the wrong place and has been moved just under AG_Label = Sheets("AG").Cells(i, "N").Value as there are some issues with certain values

Comment: @vinnie The `On Error Resume Next` masks errors from the time the statement is executed until you execute an `On Error GoTo 0`.  So, if you have a problem with the `AG_Label =` line, you should put the `On Error Resume Next` **before** that line, and the `On Error GoTo 0` **after** that line.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you want, but it should give you a better idea of how to structure a loop within a loop:

```
    Dim mrow As Long, ARow As Long, iRows As Long, srow As String
    Dim x As Long, j As Long, i As Long
    Dim AG_Label As String, AG_val As String, SNL_val As String, SNL_Label As String, M_Label As String, Rng As Range
    Dim Vval As Long, Speriod As String, aperiod As String
    Dim Count As Long, Ajay As Variant

    ARow = Sheets("AG").Range("A" & Sheets("AG").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    mrow = Sheets("Mappings").Range("A" & Sheets("Mappings").Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To ARow
        On Error Resume Next
        AG_Label = Sheets("AG").Cells(i, "N").Value
        On Error GoTo 0
        For Count = 2 To mrow
            'M_Match_1 = Sheets("Mappings").Cells(j, "P").Value
            M_Label = Sheets("Mappings").Cells(Count, "C").Value

            If AG_Label = M_Label And Sheets("Mappings").Cells(Count, "L").Value = "FRY-9C" Then
                Sheets("Mappings").Cells(Count, "J").copy
                Sheets("AG").Cells(i, "AM").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                   Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            End If    
        Next
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

---

Note: I think using error masking around the setting of the variable `AG_Label` is a bad, bad, idea.  (It means you will execute multiple times through the loop with the same value of `AG_Label`, until you get to a situation where a new, valid, value is obtained from column N.)  Below is some alternative code which stops processing of things like `#N/A`, which is what I suspect you might have been wanting the `On Error` for:

```
    Dim mrow As Long, ARow As Long, iRows As Long, srow As String
    Dim x As Long, j As Long, i As Long
    Dim AG_Label As String, AG_val As String, SNL_val As String, SNL_Label As String, M_Label As String, Rng As Range
    Dim Vval As Long, Speriod As String, aperiod As String
    Dim Count As Long, Ajay As Variant

    ARow = Sheets("AG").Range("A" & Sheets("AG").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    mrow = Sheets("Mappings").Range("A" & Sheets("Mappings").Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To ARow
        If Not IsError(Sheets("AG").Cells(i, "N").Value) Then
            AG_Label = Sheets("AG").Cells(i, "N").Value
            For Count = 2 To mrow
                'M_Match_1 = Sheets("Mappings").Cells(j, "P").Value
                M_Label = Sheets("Mappings").Cells(Count, "C").Value

                If AG_Label = M_Label And Sheets("Mappings").Cells(Count, "L").Value = "FRY-9C" Then
                    Sheets("Mappings").Cells(Count, "J").copy
                    Sheets("AG").Cells(i, "AM").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                       Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                End If    
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```